# How to make a movement of 3 images simultaneously when they are one over the other?

Tags: android, animation, simultaneous

I want to make a movement of 3 images simultaneously when they are one over the other - to get a sense of three-dimensional.

What are my options to do that?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the easiest is to create a custom view (i.e. a subclass of View) and do the rendering yourself in onDraw(Canvas canvas).